# Have can I "disable" these local timer interrupts after isolating cores?

Tags: grub2, kernel, performance, cpu, interrupts

I am trying to isolate CPU cores from the scheduler and any other unwanted activity. I have already set a few parameters on the kernel command line and updated grub:

> cat /proc/cmdline

> BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
> root=UUID=3983f8b5-04f5-4eb4-8356-5f749f7cbaa6 ro quiet splash
> isolcpus=2-15 nohz_full=2-15 rcu_nocbs=2-15 vt.handoff=7

but when I check timer interrupts:

```
sudo perf stat -e 'irq_vectors:local_timer_entry' -a -A --timeout 10000
```

it shows cores 8 and 9 have a lot of timer interrupts:

```
CPU0                    1,496      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU1                    1,346      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU2                        3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU3                        3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU4                       10      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU5                        4      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU6                        3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU7                        3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU8                      318      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU9                       20      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU10                       3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU11                       3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU12                       3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU13                       4      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU14                       3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry                                   
CPU15                       3      irq_vectors:local_timer_entry
```

How can I reduce these interrupts on cores 8 and 9?

(Any additional advice for tuning is welcome)